# openfire smack lib

Tags: java, openfire, smack

does smark library support all jabber server? or only can be use for openfire? i looking for java library that is easily portable to any jabber server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Smack is a XMPP API](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/overview.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it supports all Jabber servers .....as it is standardized!!